# Rails mongoid query string in array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3, querying

I have a Model that is called teams.

When I do Teams.account_ids it returns something like:

```
 [{"_id"=>"145952912234658", "_type"=>"Page"},
 {"_id"=>"465641870160985", "_type"=>"Account"}]
```

Lets say I want to get all Teams that have one specific account id regardless of its _type.

Something like:

```
Team.where(some_id.in => account_ids.map{|k| k["_id"))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multi-keys to effectively ignore the array when searching and then use the standard "key inside a hash" notation to look at the `_id`s:

```
Teams.where('account_ids._id' => { :$in => array_of_ids })
```

Comment: Thank you @mu_is_too_short! It worked. Could you reference me where to read more about ignoring the array as you have proposed?

Comment: The [`$eq` operator docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/eq/#array-element-equals-a-value) are probably the best starting point. There used to be a section specifically about this behavior but it seems to have gone away.